# How to download a file with Powershell System.Net.WebClient and custom user-agent string?

Tags: powershell, http, batch-file, user-agent, system.net

I am running the following command to download a file using the Powershell System.Net.WebClient method:

```
powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://domain.name/file.name','C:\file.name')"
```

Is there a way to customize the user-agent and to also retain the one-line command format?

Reason I'm asking is because the website recognizes the request as coming from a bot, and I'm getting an HTTP 403 forbidden error. When I use Internet Explorer, I can download the file without issues. I'd like to keep the one-line format because this command is being called from a batch (.bat) file in Windows.

Comment: I can understand the one liner part. But what I want to know is that have you thought of any approach for the BOT recognition?

Comment: The BOT recognition is based on the user-agent, according to the host of the website where I'm trying to download the file from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code snippet will perform the custom user agent part along with `webclient` :

```
powershell -command {
    $cli = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
    $cli.Headers['User-Agent'] = 'myUserAgentString';
    $cli.DownloadFile('https://domain.name/file.name', 'C:\file.name')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked:


`powershell -command "$cli = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$cli.Headers['User-Agent'] = 'myUserAgentString';$cli.DownloadFile('https://domain.name/file.name', 'C:\file.name')"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how to specify User Agent for Chrome

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers['User-Agent'] = 'chrome';
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```