C# Executing a Powershell Script (with Modules) works in Visual Studio Debugger but not in the fully Installed App
So im currently working on a WPF App that executes a .ps1 Script over a Process (I tried it with System.Windows.Automation before but that went worse so thats why Im using Process directly)
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"& 'C:\pathTo\test.ps1'";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => OutputDataReceived?.Invoke(sender, e);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => ErrorDataReceived?.Invoke(sender, e);

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
}

And this is the Script
Install-Module -Name BcContainerHelper -force
Import-Module -Name BcContainerHelper

$credential = New-Object pscredential 'user', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '********' -AsPlainText -Force)

$Containername = 'name'

$artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -version 22 -country de -select Latest -type Sandbox

$LicensePath = "PathToLicenseFile"


New-BcContainer -isolation hyperv -containerName $ContainerName -artifactUrl $artifactUrl -accept_eula -auth NavUserPassword -memoryLimit 5G -updateHosts -licenseFile $LicensePath -accept_outdated -Credential $credential -includeAl


Inside the Visual Studio Debugger its running as it should (If I run it in Powershell Directly its working aswell), however after I Build and install the App using velopack (manifest is enforcing Admin btw) it throws this error:
Output: BcContainerHelper version 6.0.15
Error: Add-Type : c:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\kbsrp5mv\kbsrp5mv.0.cs(3) : The type name 'WebClient' was not
Error: was found. This type was sent to assembly 'System.Net.WebClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
Error: PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd'. If necessary, add a reference to the assembly.
Error: c:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\kbsrp5mv\kbsrp5mv.0.cs(2) :
Error: c:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\kbsrp5mv\kbsrp5mv.0.cs(3) : >>> public class TimeoutWebClient : WebClient
Error: c:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\kbsrp5mv\kbsrp5mv.0.cs(4) :         {
Error: In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\6.0.15\HelperFunctions.ps1:27 chars:5
Error: + Add-Type -TypeDefinition $timeoutWebClientCode -Language CSharp - ...
Error: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except
Error: ion
Error: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
Error:
Error: Import-Module : The module manifest "C:\Program
Error: Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\6.0.15\BcContainerHelper.psd1" in the field "ModuleToProcess/RootModule"
Error: The module "BcContainerHelper.psm1" listed for processing was not processed because no valid module was found in any module directory.
Error: valid module was not found.
Error: In C:\*****\Desktop\test.ps1:2 characters:1
Error: + Import-Module -Name BcContainerHelper
Error: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (BcContainerHelper:String) [Import-Module], PSInvalidOperationExcep
Error: tion
Error: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleFileNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
Error:
Output: BcContainerHelper version 6.0.15
Error: Get-BCArtifactUrl : The command "Get-BCArtifactUrl" was found in the module "BcContainerHelper", but the module could not be loaded.
Error: could not be loaded. If you want more information, run "Import-Module BcContainerHelper".
Error: In C:\*****\Desktop\test.ps1:11 chars:16
Error: + $artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -version 22 -country de -select Late ...
Error: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-BCArtifactUrl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
Error: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
Error:
Output: BcContainerHelper version 6.0.15
Error: New-BcContainer : The "New-BcContainer" command was found in the "BcContainerHelper" module, but the module could not be loaded.
Error: could not be loaded. If you want more information, run "Import-Module BcContainerHelper".
Error: In C:\Users\*****\Desktop\test.ps1:17 chars:1
Error: + New-BcContainer -isolation hyperv -containerName $ContainerName -arti ...
Error: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (New-BcContainer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
Error: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
Error:

Hope someone had a similar Issue before and thanks already for the help!
My Execution Policy looks like this:
MachinePolicy    RemoteSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted

The psd1 and psm1 Files are Present in "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\6.0.15\

You can use absolute paths
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\BcContainerHelper\6.0.15\BcContainerHelper.psd1"

Thanks for the fast reply, same error unfortunately

Why are you shelling out to powershell.exe why not just use Powershell.Create directly in C#? Also reinstalling the module every time seems wasteful. Check it's installed using Get-InstalledModule before you try installing it

Yeah you are right, always Installing it is stupid ill fix that. I did try the Powershell.Create way before, however that got me into more trouble and since it does actually work with process inside the Debuger I choose to follow that way

See following for loading WebClient with Powershell : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819606/how-to-download-a-file-with-powershell-system-net-webclient-and-custom-user-agen

Im afraid Im a bit confused, the Issue seems to be with loading the Module, I am not downloading anything.
